# Intuition behind the definition of continuity in terms of open sets

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, continuity

I have familiarised myself with the definition of continuity in terms of limits, each point in the codomain being 'within' an $\varepsilon$ of the domain, etc...

But my lecturer has suddenly begun using the definition "a function is continuous if for all open sets, its preimage is open"

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on the intuition behind this definition so it makes better sense in my head.

Answer (score 1):

You are used to the local definition of continuity (continuity at a point $x$ is expressed using $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$).

The inverse image of open is open definition is a global version of the pointwise definition. If you look at this definition from the point of view of local continuity, it might make more sense: suppose $O$ is open and $f$ is everywhere locally continuous. Then look at any $x \in f^{-1}[O] = \{p : f(p) \in O\}$.
Then $f(x) \in O$ and as $O$ is open, so $f(x)$ is an interior point of $O$, and so there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ with $B(f(x),\varepsilon) \subseteq O$. Then the local continuity gives us a $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,x') < \delta \to d(f(x), f(x')) < \varepsilon$,and some simple set theory learns us that this means 
exactly that $f[B(x,\delta)] \subseteq B(f(x), \varepsilon) \subseteq O$. But his means that $B(x,\delta) \subseteq O$, and so $x$ is an interior point of $O$. So $f^{-1}[O]$ is open. The "wiggle room" we have around $f(x) \in O$ shows that we get some "wiggle room" around $x$ to stay inside $f^{-1}[O]$, using local continuity.

Answer (score 0):

The question mentions the classical Weierstrass-Jordan "epsilon-delta" definition of continuity. It says that a function $f:{\mathbb{R}} \to {\mathbb{R}}$ is continuous at the point ${x_0}$ when the following holds: for any positive real number $\varepsilon  > 0$, however small, there exists some positive real number $\delta  > 0$ such that for all $x$ in the domain of definition of $f$, if $\left| {x - {x_0}} \right| < \delta $ then $\left| {f\left( x \right) - f\left( {{x_0}} \right)} \right| < \varepsilon $.

We can paraphrase this definition saying: for any measure of closeness that we fix in the image space ($\varepsilon$), we can find a measure of closeness in the domain space ($\delta$) such that the function maps close points to close points.

Now, consider how we measure closeness in topological spaces. Not by means of distance, a concept that is defined in metric spaces but not in topological spaces. In topology the concept of closeness is more related to similarity or likeness. Two points are close if they share some properties. And the list of properties that the points may or may not have corresponds to the list of open sets in the topology. Having a certain property means belonging to the (open) (sub)set of all elements (of the space) that have that property.

Therefore, in a topological space, the definition would be, for any property that we fix in the image space, we can find a property in the domain space such that the function maps points with one property to points with the other. And finally, for any open set $B$ in the image space, we can find an open set ${f^{ - 1}}\left( B \right)$ in the domain space such that the function maps points from one set to the other.